Stop animation on Windows Progress Control before reaching 100%?
On a cancel request I'd like to change the standard Windows progress bar control to Paused status (for yellow), and then stop the animation without putting the bar at 100%.
Setting the state to paused works fine, but is there a way to end the animation?
TIA!!

The standard progress bar doesn't animate when it's paused/stopped does it?

it did if not 100%, granted it's styled with BCGControlBar Pro...

I have checked that the standard progress bar doesn't animate when it's paused as @JonathanPotter said. You mentioned BCGControlBar Pro. Is BCGControlBar Pro necessary in order to reproduce?
